# Create local maven repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, mvn-repo

I want to create local maven repository. I did the following steps:

1. Installed maven plugin in eclipse
2. Created one folder localrepository in apache server which is accessible using http://< my-domain>/localrepository
3. In my project pom.xml I have provided

   ```
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>repository</id>
           <url>http://<my-domain>/localMavenRepository</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   ```

But it is not resolving the jars which are on http://< my-domain>/localMavenRepository

Is there any need to provide repository?

Answer (score 63):

Set up a simple repository using a web server with its default configuration. The key is the directory structure. The documentation does not mention it explicitly, but it is the same structure as a local repository.

> To set up an internal repository just requires that you have a place to put it, and then start copying required artifacts there using the same layout as in a remote repository such as repo.maven.apache.org. [Source](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#Setting_up_the_Internal_Repository)

Add a file to your repository like this:

```sh
mvn install:install-file \
  -Dfile=YOUR_JAR.jar -DgroupId=YOUR_GROUP_ID 
  -DartifactId=YOUR_ARTIFACT_ID -Dversion=YOUR_VERSION \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -DlocalRepositoryPath=/var/www/html/mavenRepository
```

If your domain is `example.com` and the root directory of the web server is located at `/var/www/html/`, then maven can find "YOUR_JAR.jar" if configured with `<url>http://example.com/mavenRepository</url>`.

Comment: Thank you, I really don't want to setup a full-featured repository manager to run a read-only private mirror hosting a small set of artifacts that will never change.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can! For a simple repository that only publish/retrieve artifacts, you can use nginx.

1. Make sure [nginx has http dav module enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16915721/2692914), it should, but nonetheless verify it.
2. [Configure nginx http dav module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html):

   In Windows: **d:\servers\nginx\nginx.conf**

   ```
   location / {
       # maven repository
       dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
       create_full_put_path  on;
       dav_access  user:rw group:rw all:r;
   }
   ```

   In Linux (Ubuntu): **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

   ```
   location / {
           # First attempt to serve request as file, then
           # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
           # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;  # IMPORTANT comment this
           dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
           create_full_put_path  on;
           dav_access  user:rw group:rw all:r;
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to give permissions to the directory where the repo will be located:

   `sudo chmod +777 /var/www/html/repository`
3. In your project's `pom.xml` add the respective configuration:

   **Retrieve artifacts:**

   ```
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>repository</id>
           <url>http://<your.ip.or.hostname>/repository</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   ```

   **Publish artifacts:**

   ```
   <build>
       <extensions>
           <extension>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
               <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.0</version>
           </extension>
       </extensions>
   </build>
   <distributionManagement>
       <repository>
           <id>repository</id>
           <url>http://<your.ip.or.hostname>/repository</url>
       </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
   ```
4. To publish artifacts use `mvn deploy`. To retrieve artifacts, maven will do it automatically.

And there you have it a simple maven repo.

Comment: Is `sudo chmod +777` the best option here?  +664 would match `user:rw group:rw all:r`

Comment: You are right, the least privilege principle should be applied here.

Comment: Is it possible to set security tokens or passwords in this setup?

Answer (score 0):

If maven is not creating **Local Repository** i.e .m2/repository folder then try below step.

In your Eclipse\Spring Tool Suite, Go to Window->preferences-> maven->user settings-> click on Restore Defaults-> Apply->Apply and close