# How do I allow a PUT file request on Nginx server?

Tags: http, nginx, put

I am using an application which needs to `PUT` a file on a HTTP server.  I am using Nginx as the server but getting a `405 Not Allowed` error back.  Here is an example of a test with cURL:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-mpegurl' \
-d /Volumes/Extra/playlist.m3u8 http://xyz.com
```

And what I get back from Nginx:

```
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to allow the `PUT`?

Any clues would be awesome!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To add HTTP and WebDAV methods like PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, COPY and MOVE you need to compile nginx with `HttpDavModule` (`./configure --with-http_dav_module`). Check `nginx -V` first, maybe you already have the `HttpDavModule` ([I installed nginx from the Debian repository and I already have the module](https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx#Recap_of_the_different_modules_in_every_package_.28starting_Squeeze-Backports.29)).

Then change your nginx-config like that:

```
location / {
    root     /var/www;
    dav_methods  PUT;
}
```

You can get more info on the [nginx docs entry for the HttpDavModule](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html).

Comment: What if I don't need to create files, just to use additional HTTP metthods?

Comment: If you don't want to have your request handled by dav_methods and want to use PUT or DELETE methods, you should make sure these requests are not matched by the index module, but by try_files ie: try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args; in case of a typical setup with PHP

Comment: PUT is an HTTP method, not a webdav one.

Comment: @LtWorf Doesn't matter, if you want nginx to handle the request you need to use the HttpDavModule -- or forward the request to another backend, e.g. via proxy_pass. Otherwise nginx will return 405 Not Allowed.

Comment: @fnkr and how does one forward such requests to a backend? I'm only aware of backends accepting what `nginx` already accepts, i.e. `GET`, `POST`...

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for `405 Not Allowed` is that you don't have permission to write files on the destination you're `PUT`ing. If you have `HttpDavModule` and still getting this error, make sure you've given nginx write permissions where you're `PUT`ing the files.

Answer (score 0):

nginx is mainly a proxy and a lot of other things, it share something with web server, not all.

You may want to check: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/,
better is to have a rest interface and let nginx do the proxy, balancing, buffering, TSL ..

Answer (score -1):

Adding this block solved the problem for me in a Laravel application.

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```