# Sabredav with no php://input (Kohana)

Tags: php, kohana, sabredav

I have a framework that eats up `php://input` before sabredav can get to it on a PUT.

Is there a way to call setBody() in `Sabre\HTTP\Request` so I can pass this from my framework (http://kohanaframework.org) so that getBody() doesn't try to get it from the **blank** `php://input`?

I want to try to avoid hacking `Sabre\DAV\Server` and/or `Sabre\HTTP\Request` but not sure what the best approach would be.

Framework "wrapped" code is here (implementation of server.php in the Sabredav example)

https://github.com/chrisgo/kohana-sabredav/blob/master/classes/Kohana/Controller/Webdav.php

---

Original question:
[SabreDAV + Nginx + PUT (creates 0 byte file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550826/sabredav-nginx-put-creates-0-byte-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution seems to be creating a plugin to intercept the PUT method and set the body back into where sabredav is expecting it

```
public function httpPutInterceptor($method, $uri) {
    $this->server->httpRequest->setBody($this->body);
}
```

Complete module: https://github.com/chrisgo/kohana-sabredav

... now I just have to figure out why nginx is returning a 405 on a binary file `PUT` vs a text file `PUT` (correct behavior, passes it on to PHP)