# How do I get an ASP.NET site running under mono, nginx and fastcgi to accept PUT, DELETE, etc?

Tags: nginx, mono, fastcgi

I have an application that works under IIS. When I deploy the same site with the same configuration to a server running nginx with fastcgi, I get a 404 when I attempt to access a URL with a PUT command. I assume the problem is that the server is not accepting PUT as a valid verb. I tried adding webdav configurations [as noted on SO previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912270/how-do-i-allow-a-put-file-request-on-nginx-server). I setup nginx and fastcgi [as advised by the mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/nginx/). My action in MVC accepts PUT `[HttpPut, HttpDelete]`. If I perform a GET on the same URL I get a 200 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade mono to get things working. I upgraded to 3.4.0. Unfortunately I do not know what is the lowest version that supports PUT, I just know that this one worked for me.