# Okhttp PUT request to nginx server NOT ALLOWED

Tags: android, nginx, okhttp

- I can't access json with `PUT` request on nginx web server, However  same request with post request can by accessed!

  ```
  String json = "{ \"key\": \"" + value + "\" }";

  OkHttpClient  client  = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
              .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .build();

  client.newCall(new Request.Builder()
                          .url(url)
                          .put(RequestBody.create(JSON, json))
                          .build()
                  ).execute();


  public static final MediaType JSON
              = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
  ```

**Update:**

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "token: token" -X PUT -d '{ "uid": 123, "name": "Name",                         }' http://api.myserver.com
```

- Response with *`NOT ALLOWED`*

> HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) Content-Type:
>   application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Thu,
>   25 Aug 2016 21:37:02 GMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After some search i found reason:**

- You need to compile nginx with HttpDavModule [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16915721/1283715).
- But i can fix my issue from client side by adding `"_METHOD=PUT","PUT"`
  to my json.
- And convert `PUT` request to `POST`.
- Header("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT").

  ```
  String json = "{ \"_METHOD=PUT\":\"PUT\",\"key\": \"value\"\" }";


  client.newCall(new Request.Builder()
                  .url(url)
                  .post(RequestBody.create(JSON, json))
                  .Header("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT")
                  .build()
          ).execute();
  ```

**Update**

- No need to add "_METHOD=PUT","PUT" to json on body.
- Just convert `PUT` request to `POST` & add Header("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT") made it work.

  ```
  curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT" -H "token: token" -X POST -d '{ "uid": 123, "name": "Name"}' http://api.myserver.com
  ```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) Content-Type:
>   application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Thu,
>   25 Aug 2016 21:37:02 GMT