# All HTTP methods / verbs are accepted by APACHE and NGINX?

Tags: apache, web-services, http, nginx

In a lecture I recently had, one of the speakers commented that the only methods that APACHE and NGINX actually accept / support are the `GET` and `POST` methods / verbs.

The speaker further clarifies that when other methods such as `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE` and others are used, `APACHE` and `NGINX` mask the method, in other words, the methods are converted to `GET` and `POST` and passed to the application containing a flag of the old method sent. So the application will know which method was actually sent.

My question is: Are the methods / verbs really accepted by `APACHE` and the `NGINX` or the procedure contextualized in the question is what really happens?

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Apache just passes the method name on.

Comment: I don't think the speaker's statement is correct. How would Nginx or Apache support CORS if `OPTIONS` is not supported? AFAIK, Nginx may disable some HTTP methods by default, and configuration/module is needed to enable them. However, this does NOT mean those methods are not accepted/supported by Nginx. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912270/how-do-i-allow-a-put-file-request-on-nginx-server

Comment: I know the APACHE 2.2+ exists the `<Limit>` to control the http methods accepted. And it can be configured by APACHE config or _.htaccess_, like this: `<Limit POST PUT DELETE>  instructions </Limit>`. And I found this [site](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html) that talk about APACHE 2.4+ have a module called mod_allowmethods. In resume, you can define what methods can be accepted, like this: `<Location "/"> AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS </Location>`