# Location of configure file for nginx

Tags: nginx

Where is the "configure" file that [How do I allow a PUT file request on Nginx server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912270/how-do-i-allow-a-put-file-request-on-nginx-server) is referencing? I cannot find any occurrence of this file in my nginx-related directories:

[image]

As for what my etc/nginx directory looks like:

[image]

Comment: But how do I execute the configure command in the post then? ./nginx.conf instead of ./configure?

Comment: The referenced answer is discussing building `nginx` from source. You will need to download the source.

Comment: Alright, got it.