# how to add SBT resolver (server side)

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy, resolver

The official SBT documentation mentions own resolvers ([link](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Resolvers)) from SBT point of view. The question is **how to create own public server** from whence dependencies can be downloaded (via resolvers from SBT).

Assuming having simple apache/php webhosting with domain, can I just place `.jar` files somewhere with some naming conventions and eventually use: (example)

```
resolvers += "My projects repos" at "http[s]://downloads.my-domain.tld/sbt"
```

If so, what are the naming conventions and best practice? If not, what is required? Does one need the access to *nix server? Should something be installed or configured?

Thanks for help

Comment: I'm not sure but probably you should create your own maven repository. Example instruction is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834141/create-local-maven-repository. I don't do it, but probably it will works.

Comment: I don't understand - is maven repository just a bunch of files with some naming convention and structure? Or do I need some sophisticated server to serve?

Comment: Here is some informations about publishing projects: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally I solved it simply by adding this line to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mypack1.pack2" % "projectName" % "version" from "http://domain.tld/myLib.jar"
```

Comment: Wonderful. I did not know about this syntax and it worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

We have [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) installed to host our own `.jar` files. It also allows us to keep `.jar` files private.

Comment: This is definitely working possibility but don't you possibly know whether similar behavior can be achieved using only LAMP service?

Comment: That is probably doable, please check the documentation here on custom layouts: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html